# Substituting "comes to" with "expresses as/as to" for equivalence

Tags: expressions, equivalence

Ex. "passing the exam can be expressed **as to** get high marks above ten". I wanted to say "passing the exam comes to get high marks above ten"
Is this sentence correct? How to use "expresses..as" in such a scenario please?

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence is:

> Passing the exam can be expressed as getting high marks above ten.

A more common way to say it would be:

> Passing the exam requires getting high marks above ten.